# Find all $7$-Sylow subgroups of $S_{14}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Recently, while studying for my group theory class, I tried to solve the following problem

> Find all $7$-Sylow subgroups of $S_{14}$.

Since the order of $S_{14}$ is $14!$ I know that $P$, a $7$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{14}$, has order $|P|=7^2$. By a previous result this implies that $P$ is abelian. Hence $P$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{49}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{7}\times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. But given an element $\sigma \in S_{14}$ and its decomposition into disjoint cycles $\sigma=\sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$
$$
|\sigma|={\rm lcm}(|\sigma_1|, \cdots, |\sigma_n|).
$$
Since the order of a cycle equals the length of the cycle itself I know that in $S_{14}$, $|\sigma_i| \leq 14$. If $|\sigma|=49$ then $|\sigma_i|$ divides $49$. Since $|\sigma_i| \leq 14$ we must have $|\sigma_i| =7$. But then ${\rm lcm}(|\sigma_1|, \cdots, |\sigma_n|)=7$. So I conclude that there is no element of order $49$ in $S_{14}$. Hence $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_{49}$ is not possible and $P$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{7}\times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. In this case I must find all subgroups of $S_{14}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{7}\times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$.

> So my questions are:
>
> - Are there any mistakes in what I have done so far?
> - Could someone give me a hint on how to find all the isomorphic subgroups for $\mathbb{Z}_{7}\times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$?

I know that all its elements are of order $7$ and that it is generated by the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. So I tried to find all elements of order $7$ in $S_{14}$ which are the $7$-cycles and the product of two disjoint $7$-cycles (correct?). But I don't know how to find which of these pairs are going to generate the subgroups I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: The two 7-cycles generating a Sylow subgroup must commute. Two 7-cycles commute if and only if they are either powers of each other or disjoint. Which alternative will work for you?

Comment: This looks good so far! Remember that $P$ is abelian. In particular, the two generators need to commute. That should reduce the number of pairs significantly.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen! If they are powers of each other it won't work right? At least it seems to me it won't because the isomorphic group $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ is such that its own generators are not powers of each other.

Comment: Thanks for the help @EikeSchulte!

Comment: Correct, if they are each others powers, they only generate a group of order $7$. So you need two disjoint 7-cycles. There's room for them in $S_{14}$. Just barely :-)

Comment: Furthermore, recall that when you have found one Sylow 7, the others are conjugate to it. You can then reflect what you know about the cycle types of conjugates in symmetric groups. Counting the number of distinct Sylow 7s of $S_{14}$ takes a bit more work. You may want to begin by counting the number of Sylow 7s of $S_7$. Hint: Each of those contains a unique 7-cycle of the form $(12abcde)$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are the numbers $3,4,5,6,7$ in some order.